# how codeigniter join two tables to have both Id columns

Tags: join, codeigniter-3

I want to join two tables that I have both Id columns in join table by codeigniter.

I want both id column from comment and users tables

I write below code

```
 $this->db->select('users.name as user_full_name, users.id as userid', false);
    $this->db->from('users');

    $this->db->select()
        ->from('comment')
        ->where('project_id', $projectId)
        ->where('user_id', $user_id)
        ->join('users', 'comment.user_id_from =userid')
        ->order_by("comment.id", "asc");
    return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

but face error, I do not know why

error:

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM (`users`, `comment`) JOIN `users` ON `comment`.`user_id_from` =`userid` W' at line 1

SELECT users.name as user_full_name, users.id as userid, * FROM (`users`, `comment`) JOIN `users` ON `comment`.`user_id_from` =`userid` WHERE `project_id` = '3' AND `user_id` = '84' ORDER BY `comment`.`id` ASC

please show me how to solve it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
 $this->db->select('*,comment.id as comment_id,users.user_id as user_id,users.name as user_name');
 $this->db->from('comment');
 $this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
 $this->db->join('users', 'users.user_id = comment.id');
 $this->db->order_by("comment.id", "asc");
 return $this->db->get()->result_array();
```

it return all `user and comment` table data

may be this codeigniter query help you out